# Getting List from Session.GetObjects

Tags: c#, devexpress

In my code, there's a class: `Person`.

When I call:

```
var persons = session.GetObjects(session.GetClassInfo(typeof(Person)), criteria, null, 0, false, true);
```

`persons` variable gets `ICollection` object.

Question1: Why it is not possible to use `persons` as `IEnumerable<T>` although `ICollection` extends `IEnumerable` ?

Question2: How to build a `List` instance using `persons`? I googled it and `ToList()` method is not available for `persons` even `using System.Linq;` is present in the code.

**UPDATE**

On the line of code:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = (IEnumerable<Person>)session.GetObjects(session.GetClassInfo(typeof(Person)), criteria, null, 0, false, true);
```

I get the runtime error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestProject.BusinessObjects.Person]'.

Comment: Re "Question 1" - what makes you think it isn't possible? What happens? Do you get an error? If so: what error *exactly*?

Comment: Re "Question 2" - `ToList()` is on `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`. You need the `<T>`. Presumably it is `IEnumerable<Person>` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've posted an update to my post.

Comment: @mjwills `IEnumerable<T>` I've posted an update to my post.

Comment: `.Cast<Person>()` or `.OfType<Person>()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert a non-generic collection to generic collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731831/best-way-to-convert-a-non-generic-collection-to-generic-collection)

Comment: @mjwills thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are using the [Session.GetObjects](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.Xpo.Session.GetObjects.method(03T4hA)) method. According to the documentation, **this method supports the internal infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code**.

To get objects from a session, I suggest you use the XPCollection or the XPQuery:

```
XPCollection<Person> persons = new XPCollection<Person>(session1, criteria);
```

Comment: old but good. Saved me Time :-)